# What is the status of FlinkML?

Tags: apache-flink, flinkml

Don't see much recent discussion about FlinkML - is it dying or dead?

What are some examples of some interesting recent live usages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [community decided to drop the old flink-ml library](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/SURVEY-Usage-of-flink-ml-and-DISCUSS-Delete-flink-ml-td29057.html) from the 1.9 release. Meanwhile a new machine learning library has been developed under the umbrella of [FLIP-39](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-39+Flink+ML+pipeline+and+ML+libs), and is being extended under [FLINK-12470](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12470).

[Alink](https://github.com/alibaba/Alink/blob/master/README.en-US.md) may also be of interest.